# Before Insert Trigger on not acting as expected

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I have a table called film:

```
  CREATE TABLE film (
  film_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  title varchar2(255),
  description varchar2(255),
  release_year NUMBER(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  language_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  original_language_id NUMBER(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  rental_duration NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 3 NOT NULL,
  rental_rate NUMBER(4,2) DEFAULT '4.99',
  length NUMBER(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  replacement_cost NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT '19.99' NOT NULL,
  rating varchar2(8) DEFAULT 'G',
  special_features varchar2(255) DEFAULT NULL
  );
```

And I tried to make a trigger that increased rental rates of films depending on the special feature it has (can only have one). And I came up with the following trigger (for oracle and it compiles with no error)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INCREASE_RENTAL_RATE
BEFORE INSERT ON FILM
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    change number(4,2);
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('mytrigger STARTING');
IF (:NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES = 'Trailers') THEN
    change := 0.1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Trailer Read');
END IF;
IF (:NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES = 'Commentaries') THEN
    change := 0.5;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Commentary read');
END IF;
IF (:NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES = 'Deleted Scenes') THEN
    change := 0.2;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('DS read');
END IF;
IF (:NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES = 'Behind the Scenes') THEN
    change := 0.2;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('BS read');
END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('new=' || :NEW.rental_rate);
UPDATE FILM
SET FILM.RENTAL_RATE = FILM.RENTAL_RATE + change
WHERE FILM.FILM_ID = :NEW.FILM_ID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('new=' || :NEW.rental_rate);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('mytrigger FINISHED');
END;​
```

Since it compiles with no errors I don't know where to look for problems, but it's not working, I used a dummy example:

```
   INSERT INTO FILM VALUES(20001, 'SUPREMO BORROWERS', 'An exasdafaf', 1978, 1, NULL, 5, '2.99', 52, '11.99', 'PG-13', 'Trailers');
```

In it, the rental rate is 2.99 and it continues to be 2.99 when I select the film with film_id = 20001...

Here is the output received:
"mytrigger STARTING
Trailer Read
new=2.99
new=2.99
mytrigger FINISHED

1 row(s) inserted."

Which means it knows it had a trailer but the update isn't working

Can anybody help me understand why?

Thanks :)

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ is not _invoked_ ? Or don't update data as expected ? What was your _"dummy example"_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a before trigger, and you are attempting to directly update the row which is about to be inserted / updated in the table (which might not exist yet, and if it did, would likely be overwritten again by the actual update). Instead of the table update, simply change the value of the `new` pseudo row:

```
:new.RENTAL_RATE := :new.RENTAL_RATE + change;
```

**Edit**

As per below comments, the above didn't work for the OP in this case. However, the following did:

```
SELECT :new.RENTAL_RATE + change INTO :new.RENTAL_RATE FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Compilation failed, line 17 (01:50:22) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid optionCompilation failed, line 17 (01:50:22) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignoredCompilation failed, line 18 (01:50:22) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement...

Comment: Strange. My answer is based on [this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#sthref1237)

Comment: Here's another possible cause - the definitions `rental_rate NUMBER(4,2)` and `change NUMBER(5,2)` differ. Try changing `change` to (4,2). [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13934170/314291)

Comment: And one last thought : `SELECT :new.RENTAL_RATE + change INTO :new.RENTAL_RATE FROM DUAL;`

Comment: *Phew* I was doubting my sanity. Would you mind ticking my answer please? Also, out of interest, does `SET :new.RENTAL_RATE := :new.RENTAL_RATE + change;` work? i.e. this might just be a SqlPlus artifact?

Comment: SET :new.RENTAL_RATE := :new.RENTAL_RATE + change;
Doesn't work but the INTO one does :)

Just ticked your answer, thx!